# insert json data into text datatype of POSTGRES table column

Tags: json, postgresql

I am trying to insert json data into text datatype of postgres table.

For example, table1 is having columns as:

```
id | name | occupation | skills 
--------------------------------------------------------
1  | John | engineer   | {"java":"true","oracle":"true"} 
---------------------------------------------------------
2  | mary | engineer   | {".net":"true","mysql":"true"}
```

Here in the above table skills are of type text and we are inserting json data in it.
How can I insert json data into text datatype of postgres table?

Comment: you should treat the json string as text and wrap it in quotes. Then it should insert fine.

Comment: Use double quotes, this should be the only restriction... Are you writing to the DB with PHP? [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: I am writing in postgres db itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your json to string, then try to save

```
"{\"java\":\"true\",\"oracle\":\"true\"}"
```

If you are inserting json data directly to postgres db, try converting json to string from [online converter](http://tools.knowledgewalls.com/jsontostring)